# Angular js matching the element and fetching the result

Tags: html, angularjs, json

If item matches the Array element filter the result
have the below json structure

```
  [{"id": "1", "name":"product1","items": ["item1","item2"],},
  {"id": "2", "name":"product2","items": ["item4","item3"],},
  {"id": "3", "name":"product3","items": ["item5","item1"],}]
```

Requirement is if i select item1 from drop down i need to filter the entire object which contains item1.
I am new to angular js can any one help me out

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter` in `ng-repeat`

**via text-box**

```
Search by item: <input type="text" ng-model="search.items">
<div ng-repeat="product in data | filter:search">
  {{product}}
</div>
```

**via drop-down**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedThana" ng-options="t.items for t in data">
    <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
<div ng-repeat="product in data | filter:selectedThana">
  {{product}}
</div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.data = [{"id": "1", "name":"product1","items": ["item1","item2"],},
  {"id": "2", "name":"product2","items": ["item4","item3"],},
  {"id": "3", "name":"product3","items": ["item5","item1"],}];
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedThana" ng-options="t.items for t in data">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                    </select>
<div ng-repeat="product in data | filter:selectedThana">
  {{product}}
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. in drop down i will have item1,itme2,itm3 if select item one

Comment: {"id":"1","name":"product1","items":["item1","item2"]} {"id":"3","name":"product3","items":["item5","item1"]} these two arrys should get selected

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using $filter,

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="user" ng-change="getselected(user)" ng-options="code.name as code.name for code in optionsdownload">
</select>
```

**Controller**

```
 $scope.getselected = function(item){
    $scope.wholeobj = $filter("filter")($scope.optionsdownload, item);
 }
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Q1GFY1tLqKTO73CdaJyT?p=preview)**